# Habilitar CORS via JavaScript (Phonegap)

Tags: javascript, ajax, html5, apache-cordova

Estou criando uma aplicação Phonegap que consome uma Web API (Web Service), e preciso acessar um domínio externo. Pesquisando pela web encontrei que devia habilitar o CORS via JavaScript para ter a possibilidade de acessar outros domínios. Desta maneira gostaria de saber de que maneira faria isso.

Segue abaixo o código de uma busca feita pelo app.

```
function find()
{
  var urlAl = 'http://*********/api/Produtos';
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");

  $.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    dataType : "jsonp",
    url : urlAl,
    success: function(data){
      alert(data);
    },
    error: function()
    {
      alert("erro");  
    }
});
```

Comment: Para qual plataforma você está desenvolvendo? A solução varia (o problema não é bem CORS), segundo a documentação: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.0rc1/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide

Comment: Esta questão já existe no site não lhe ajuda? Caso não, qual a diferença do seu problema? É importante mostrar que você fez buscas no site antes de postar pertuntas similares e mostrar como o seu caso se diferencia. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5959/cors-no-nodejs-sem-o-uso-de-frameworks

Comment: @Nigini se é a mesma questão então o melhor seria marcar como duplicata, assim a questão é bloqueada, mas não deletada e ainda faz referencia a questão que seria a "primeira".

Comment: Opa @GuilhermeNascimento. Pois é, não tenho certeza, pois a outra questão usa um framework não citado aqui. Neste caso preferi que Gabriel avaliasse e melhorasse a pergunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## No PhoneGap

De outras perguntas do StackOverflow (traduzidas livremente para o português):

> ## [O PhoneGap suporta cors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24909463/do-phonegap-support-cors)
>
> ### RE:
>
> Sim ele suporta, tudo o que você tem que fazer é adicionar essa linha para seu arquivo `config.xml`:
>
> ```
> <access origin=“http://example.com” />
> ```
>
> Você também pode fazer isso:
>
> ```
> <access origin=“*” />
> ```

Outra resposta:

> ## [Cors e Apps PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297169/cors-and-phonegap-apps)
>
> Com o PhoneGap você pode só fazer requests XHR diretamente para servidores remotos e eles deveriam simplesmente funcionar. A política de `Cross-domain` não se aplica para o PhoneGap (por diversas razões, basicamente porque seu App está rodando a partir do URI `file://` no dispositivo).
>
> Por favor tenha em mente que você terá que configurar uma *whitelist* para seus Apps acessarem domínios externos. Por favor confira esse link:
>
> http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.0rc1/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide

Espero que isso esclareça sua dúvida; abaixo estão instruções para se isso fosse um request no navegador.

## No navegador

Seria necessário que você mudasse seu servidor para suportar cors, adicionando uma Header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` para o domínio que o Phonegap rode por cima - pode ser um wildcard (`*`) para aceitar todas as origens. Dependendo do tipo de request que você precisar fazer, será necessário implementar rotas “pre-flight”, que são apenas rotas `OPTIONS` para sua aplicação, que respondam com os headers. Isso não deve ser difícil de fazer, mas vai depender do seu servidor.

No Node.js, por exemplo, você poderia usar o módulo [`cors`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) e resolver o problema no servidor com uma ou duas linhas:

```
app.use(cors());
app.options(‘*’, cors());
```

Isso feito, bastaria mudar seu request para habilitar o CORS no client-side ([documentação](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)):

```
$.ajax({
  // …
  crossDomain: true,
});
```

Caso você quisesse repassar/receber cookies do servidor, você precisaria fazer outra modificação:

```
$.ajax({
  // …
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true,
  },
});
```

Nesse caso o servidor também teria que incluir o header `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`. No caso do Node.js, bastaria mudar `cors()` para `cors({ credentials: true })`.

Comment: Obrigado plea ajuda Yamada, mas dessa forma ainda não acessa a Web API, posso estar fazendo algo de errado no código da pesquisa?

Comment: Acho que é provável… Tente mandar mais informação na pergunta! :)