# Como ultrapassar o Same-Origin Policy e consumir um webservice SOAP com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, apache-cordova, soap

Estou a construir uma aplicação mobile com recurso ao PhoneGap para iOS, Android e Windows Phone e preciso de fazer a ligação a um webservice SOAP para várias funcionalidades da aplicação.

Tenho tentado fazê-lo com recurso a Ajax, mas tenho sempre o mesmo problema: bate no Same-Origin Policy.

Como posso ultrapassar este problema? Há algo que deva colocar do meu lado ou do lado do servidor (Java)?

Mudar para REST não é opção aqui. Tem mesmo que ser SOAP e a chamada tem mesmo que ser em JavaScript por causa do PhoneGap.

Obrigada pela atenção desde já!

Comment: Já experimentou [habilitar CORS](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51942/215)? P.S. Acho que me enganei, CORS parece não se aplicar ao Phonegap. Mas a resposta à pergunta linkada dá mais informações sobre como acessar domínios externos nessa plataforma.

Comment: Habilitei o CORS do lado do PhoneGap, mas não percebi como fazê-lo do lado do navegador. Será isso que me falta? E sim, como se faz? Não consegui compreender pela resposta nem pelos links dessa pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema. Para o conseguir tivemos que fazer uma alteração no projecto do webservice, permitindo o CORS no JBoss. Podem ler sobre a alteração que fizemos [aqui](http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter.html).