# Por que ninguém conecta no meu socket.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Olá!

Tenho uma api com o seguinte código de exemplo:

```
const app = require('express')()
const http = require('http').Server(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(http)
const cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors())
app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    io.emit('teste', {status: true})
    res.send('socket.io')
})

app.get('/socket.io', (req, res)=>{
    res.send(req.params)
})


app.post('/socket.io', (req, res)=>{
    res.send(req.body)
})
io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log('concted');
    socket.on('connect', data =>{
        io.emit('teste', true)
    })
    socket.on('teste', teste =>{
        socket.emit('teste', teste)
    })
})

app.listen(4000, ()=>{
    console.log('listen on 4000');
})
```

Estou usando usando como dependência:

```
"cors": "^2.8.5",
"express": "^4.17.1",
"socket.io": "^3.0.4"
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>    
        <script src="socket.js"></script>    
        <script>
            var socket = io('http://localhost:4000')
            socket.on('teste', data =>{
                console.log('test');
            })
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

O conteúdo do javascript eu copiei [daqui](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/3.0.4/socket.io.js)

Ao acessar a página não aparece que conectou

Na api, se mudo o listen para

```
http.listen(4000, ()=> {
})
```

Ao tenta acessar através da página html, tenho esse resultado no console

Eu tenho problema de cors

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:4000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NQCAgmT' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Já tentei de diversas formas

```
/*
var whitelist = ['http://localhost']
const options = (req, callback) =>{
  var corsOptions;
  if (whitelist.indexOf(req.header('Origin')) !== -1) {
    corsOptions = { origin: true } // reflect (enable) the requested origin in the CORS response
  } else {
    corsOptions = { origin: false } // disable CORS for this request
  }
  callback(null, corsOptions) // callback expects two parameters: error and options
}*/
var corsOptions = {
    origin: '*',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204 
  }
  app.use(cors(corsOptions));

//app.use(cors(options))
app.use((req, res, next) =>{
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
  });
```

Comment: Acho que o protocolo deveria ser `ws://` e não `http://`, posso estar errado nunca usei o 
 `socket.io` em especifico.

Comment: também não conecta

Comment: Sobre o erro apresentado CORS eu vi que você esta usando `app.use(cors())` porem ele continua reclamando que não esta permitido, Essa é uma pergunta relacionado que talvez ajude: [CORS no NodeJS sem o uso de Frameworks](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5959/3774)

Comment: Creio que não seja retorno e sim, o frontend ter acesso ao back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri.

Depois de tanta pesquisa, findei achando onde pesquisar usando o firefox

Na declaração do socket.io

```
const io = require('socket.io')(http)
```

Eu mudei pra isso aqui

```
const io = require('socket.io')(http, {
    cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"]
      }
})
```

Caso alguém tenha o mesmo problema que eu

Comment: Show! as versões novas do socket.io andam exigindo cors, mas fica aqui a dica que  quando você for executar isso em produção deve colocar os domínios apropriados.

Comment: Exatamente! Isso mesmo